# Why does my LAN file sharing speeds never go beyond my internet subscription download speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, isp

I am fairly new to networking but I can understand its basics. I recently found out that my file copying over wireless LAN speed is low and specifically doesn't exceed my maximum download speed that I bought through my ISP.

To explain :

I have a home modem that has a 4MB plan, so my download speed never exceeds 400Kb/s. When I connect my Two computers or generally any two devices and try to copy a file from one to an other, that file transfer speed, though from a local machine to a local machine is also capped at 400Kb/s.

This can't be because my local network is not affected by my ISP in any way.

I must say that I didn't do any special configuring like create NATs or any static IPs/MACs.

A Second Point :

When I Upgraded my Plan to 20Mb/s, what I found is that the maximum speed for file transfer also jumped up to 2000Kb/s average. which does point an issue in my modem, I guess.

**EDIT:**
To transfer I use FTP and HTTP file Download (basically make a file available over the network and download it from an other device via browser)

My question is : is this normal ? or is there a way to fix it ?, especially if I want to stream files from one device to an other and I need a higher transfer rate.

Comment: How are you doing the file transfer? Windows network folders? FTP? Do you have a NAS?

Comment: Are you actually using local IP addresses to connect to your local devices?

Comment: Yes I am, i often open an ftp server on one device and a client on the other side. all within my local Network